# Qt DropActions: What is ActionMask for?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

You can set `dropActions` using the usual bitmask for flags. From [the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#DropAction-enum), we have the following possible drop actions:

```
Action                  Value       Result   
Qt::CopyAction          0x1  (1)    Copy the data to the target.
Qt::MoveAction          0x2  (2)    Move the data from the source to the target.
Qt::LinkAction          0x4  (4)    Create a link from the source to the target.
Qt::ActionMask          0xff (255)  [none given in docs]
Qt::IgnoreAction        0x0  (0)    Ignore the action (do nothing with the data).
```

I am confused by the `ActionMask` action. I have not found any discussion of it (e.g., [here](http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/qt/dnd.html#drag-and-drop-actions) or [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/34064-Drop-Actions)), or even any examples of it in use (such as at Nullege). Its value is *11111111*, so any time you bitwise `or` it with any of the other dropActions you will just end up with `ActionMask` again.

So, what is `ActionMask` for? When is it used? Where is it documented?

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the accepted answer, there is one DropAction I left out of the enumeration, and this is probably key:

```
TargetMoveAction    0x8002 (32770 in dec, 1000000000000010 in bin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a mask is a value used to include or exclude certain bits of another value, using bitwise operations.

The definition of the [DropAction enum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#DropAction-enum), includes another flag:

```
    Qt::TargetMoveAction    0x8002
```

which is outside of the range of the mask. So the mask could be used to screen out such values, like this:

```
>>> from PySide.QtCore import Qt
>>> a = Qt.CopyAction | Qt.TargetMoveAction
>>> int(a)
32771
>>> int(a & Qt.ActionMask)
3
```

and vice-versa:

```
>>> int(a & ~Qt.ActionMask)
32768
```

As to *why* it might be used: Qt4 uses it in precisely *one* place in its source code, namely the `QtDropActionToDndOperation` function in [gui/kernel/qmotifdnd_x11.cpp](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/kernel/qmotifdnd_x11.cpp#L138). Make of that what you will...

Comment: I should have included that dropaction in my enum...It seems key: I wonder if those were added to qt together to be used in the way you suggest.

Comment: Interesting that `TargetMoveAction` ends with `10`, so it implicitly includes `MoveAction`.

Comment: @neuronet. Qt provides masks in several of its enums, and the most common use seems to be to provide an easily maintainable way to include all possible flags without having to know in advance what they actually are. Given that `TargetMoveAction` is not used in the same way on all platforms, it seems to make sense that it has a value outside of the range of the mask.